# ExtJS 4.2 building grid columns and rows dynamically (the interface slows down)

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have a `gridpanel` that I build dynamically from server.

The result is the following image:

[image]

The code that I'm using after I get the data from the server is:

success: function(response, opts) {
    var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
    if (obj.success) {

```
    gridStore.model.setFields(obj.data.metaData.fields);

    grid.reconfigure(gridStore, obj.data.metaData.columns);

    gridStore.loadRawData(obj.data.storeData, false);

}
```

},

Answer (score 1):

Try suspendLayouts and suspendEvents before re-configuring the grid and turn it on later

```
success: function(response, opts) {
    var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText); 
    if (obj.success) {
        Ext.suspendLayouts();//Suspending layout should fast things up
        gridStore.suspendEvents(); //If needed suspend the events too

        gridStore.model.setFields(obj.data.metaData.fields);
        grid.reconfigure(gridStore, obj.data.metaData.columns);
        gridStore.loadRawData(obj.data.storeData, false);

        Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
        gridStore.resumeEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add  gridStore.suspendEvents(); / gridStore.resumeEvents(); then there is no data displayed in the grid.

Comment: try gridRef.getView().refresh() after resumeEvents.. (does suspendLayouts alone helps?)